# Is there a good migration management/clean-up strategy after completing a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As I go through the development of an application, in my development environment, I make mistakes and create tables that need to be modified later - as I use the app and see the folly of earlier design decisions.

But when I push to production, I don't want to replicate all those changes when I can just create the 'perfect' table in one migration.

Is there a strategy or something I can use that can help me do that?

Answer (score 2):

If this is the initial push to production, you should be able to copy your `schema.rb` contents (which should reflect the schema after all migrations were applied) into one giant migration file, and remove all previous migration files.

If your production environment has already been created and the database has been migrated up to a point, then you'll need to use something more intelligent that can bridge the gap between the current state and the latest schema.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any such project at this time.

Comment: Interesting idea about copying the schema to one big-ass migration file. That's a clever work-around.

But you are right about an existing production environment...that's what I am looking for :)